# LWJGL: Is glMatrixMode() deprecated? Or am I missing something?

Tags: java, deprecated, lwjgl

So I was reading through [this](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Version_selection#Display.create.28.29) article on the LWJGL wiki, and it mentions, "when using a 'forward compatible' context any functionality flagged as deprecated will be removed."

Now when I implemented the forward compatibility with the display, the compiler threw an IllegalStateExceptionError whenever I call glMatrixMode() along with other rendering functions.  When I remove the forward compatibility, it works just fine.  So is glMatrixMode() deprecated? If so, what is the new way of initializing my rendering mode?

Comment: Passing the MVP matrix to the shader I believe. Most people use the GLM library.

Comment: So I *need* to work with shaders with future versions?

Comment: I believe so, GLM is C++ though I'm not sure what the java equivalent is.

Comment: Alright.  Now I have to actually use shaders!  I was trying to avoid those lol

Comment: Yeah OpenGL 4 spec has no matrix operations anymore.

Comment: That is the greatest news I've heard all day! Well, time to work on matrix functions.. haha. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

http://java.net/projects/vecmath

This is a java library that's recommended for matrix operations since newer specs of OpenGL no longer support matrix operations.

For forward compatibility no older code can use these functions.